# Authentication/Decryption using a subset of Key

Tags: cryptography

Is there a cryptographic system where a user(s) can be authenticated (or they can unlock a document) only if they present a subset, of more than one, the of valid keys?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Please ask on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Non-anonymous authentication

If you don't require the users contributing to the successful authentication to remain anonymous, it's easy: The server generates a random nonce and sends it to the subset of users. Each user signs the nonce with his/her private signature key and sends the signature to the server. The server verifies each signature and if enough of them are present then the subset has successfully authenticated.

#### (Anonymous) Decryption

Someone else here might know of an RFC or a library for that purpose, but If there is none, I would design it like this: Split the secret into `n` parts where `k` of them are necessary to recreate the secret using [Shamir's Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing). For each of the `n` users encrypt a different part of the split up secret with his/her public encryption key. When `k` of them decrypt their part of the split up secret, they can recreate the secret.

If the public key encryption is deterministic you can even make it anonymous in the sense that if you can get to the secret you can check that each other subset of `k` users would also be able to get the secret: In preparation of the protocol run you also have to designate a fixed x-coordinate for each user in addition to the public encryption key. When a subset of users successfully recreated the secret and thus the polynomial, they can evaluate it at each of the users x-coordinate and encrypt it with their public key. If the result is identical to those generated by the server, every subset of `k` users can decrypt the secret.

(Note that deterministic encryption has some caveats. For example, if the plaintext space is small, an attacker can just encrypt each plaintext and compare the result to the given ciphertext.)

#### Corollary: Anonymous authentication

Using the anonymous decryption you can create an anonymous authentication protocol by having the server encrypt a random nonce for `k` out of `n` people in the way described above and send it to the subset of users. They decrypt the nonce, check that each subset of `k` users would also be able to decrypt it and send the nonce back to the server.